# registering multiple routes in sammy.js

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I want to register multiple routes for one callback like below. I sperated them with "," character just for show what i mean. Is it possible to do such a thing ?

```
this.get('/Posts/MostVoteds, /Posts/Mostpopular, /Posts/blabla', function (ctx) {

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as [paths](http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes) could be defined both as strings and regular expressions you could try merging paths mentioned in a single regular expression, i.e.

```
this.get(/^\/Posts\/(MostVoteds|Mostpopular|blabla)/, function (ctx) {
    // some code here
});
```